# How can I find the tag wiki for a tag that has been synonymized with another?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

The system allows to synonymize tags where the resulting tag does not have a wiki, but the source one had. How in that case I can find the wiki of the source tag without breaking the synonymized pair?

[The orphaned wiki page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/orphan-wikis) doesn't contain that wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) queries which return:

- [Tag wiki & excerpt for synonymized tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1618142/tag-infos-for-synonymized-tags)

  - In order to get the contents of a synonymized tag's wiki or excerpt, you are interested in the "revisions" column returned by the query.
  - For example, the result from that query has a link to the revision history of the ["agile-processes" wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13115060/revisions). That tag is now a [synonym of "agile"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile/synonyms). The wiki for "agile" [is a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4998355/revisions).
- [Orphaned tag wikis & excerpts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1231351/orphaned-tag-wikis)

  - The disadvantage here is that you don't get the name of the tag in the query result. (IIRC somebody mentioned to me that the mods do not see the name of the tags in the list of orphaned tag wikis either. Maybe in some cases, you might be lucky and it might be possible to get the old tag info [from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224235056/https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile-processes/info).)

I used Stack Overflow as an example here - but in SEDE one can switch to any site on the network.

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week. (So you won't see the most recent synonyms there - you'll have to wait for the next update if you need to see one of those.)

And I will add a collection of [some other tag-related queries](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2023/8/20) which might sometimes be interesting.

---

The OP suggested in comments that one could obtain the old tag-info simply by going to `tags/{old-tag-name}`. However, this only works sometimes. In the example I mentioned above, the link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile-processes/info redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile/info.
However, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-devops-server/info does *not* redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfs/info - despite [being a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfs/synonyms).

One conjecture mentioned in the comments was that the redirect is only added if the tags are merged - but I did not find any sources to confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for the query, but it seems that everything I need to know that the old wiki can be obtained via "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/{old-tag}/info"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Does that actually work? In the example I've mentioned above, the link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile-processes/info redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile/info - which is the new tag, not the old one.

Comment: Interesting. This works on ruSO for recently synonymized tag ["kernel"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/kernel/info). Maybe it's still caching, or depends on the existence/absence of wiki for old tag?

Comment: Another thought that redirecting may occur for merged and synonymized tags, but not for synonymized only.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Checking on ruSO, a link for the [tag-info for notifications](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/notifications/info) redirects to the [tag-info for уведомления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info). Perhaps it depends on merging - as you suggested. I do not know whether this behavior is documented somewhere.